# Java performance of byte[] vs. char[] for file stream

Tags: java, io

I'm writing a program that reads a file (uses custom buffer, 8KB), then finds a keyword in that buffer. Since Java provides two type of streams: character & byte, I've implemented this using both `byte[]` and `char[]` for buffering.

I just wonder, which would be faster and better for performance, since a `char` is 2 `byte` and when using `Reader` to read up `char[]`, the `Reader` will perform converting back from `byte` to `char`, which I think could make it slower than using only `byte[]`.

Comment: Why don't you compare the implementation yourself?

Comment: Actually I did. The result seems that byte is a little faster but not significantly. I just want to ask for more opinions.

Comment: Actually I asked a similiar question several days ago. Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047569/char-to-byte-optimize-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a byte array will be faster:

- You don't have the bytes to characters decoding step, which is at least a copy loop, and possibly more depending on the Charset used to do the decoding.
- The byte array will take less space, and hence save CPU cycles in GC / initialization.

However:

- Unless you are searching huge files, the difference is unlikely to be significant.
- The byte array approach *could* FAIL if the input file is not encoded in an 8 bit character set.  And even if it works (as it does for UTF-8 & UTF-16) there are potential issues with matching characters that span buffer boundaries.

(The reason that byte-wise treatment works for UTF-8 and UTF-16 is that the encoding makes it easy to distinguish between the first unit (byte or short) and subsequent units of an encoded character.)

Comment: I've tested my `byte` implementation with Unicode file and it works. And the size of files ranging from 1MB-6MB (index file of dictionary).

Comment: @Stephen C Could you help to explain the code refactor to the velocity in my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047569/char-to-byte-optimize-java

Comment: Not without spending a lot of time doing research work that **you could do yourself**.  Hint: use a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a binary file you're reading use a byte array.

If it's a text file and you're going to be using the contents like strings later then you should use a char array.

Comment: It's a text file. However, I just find a keyword in a file, so implementing using byte[] works fine for me. I just wonder which could result in better than the other. In this situation, I consider a text file or a String is just a byte array and the problem becomes finding a smaller byte array in bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

This stack overflow question [file-streaming-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728523/file-streaming-in-java) talks about streaming files efficiently in java.

I particularly like [this reference article](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly)

On large files, you quickly have advantages of speed using only bytes, so if you can decode the pattern through bytes you could definitively gain a few precious cycles.

If your files are small, or you don't have so many, maybe it's not worth the trouble.